# Tabulator JS : Problem with autocomplete option, doesn't work on the firts click

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tabulator

I have a problem with the autocomplete option, the list of values appear only at the second click on the cell.
do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Exemple of tabulator configuration impacted

```
{
title: "Catégorie", field: "Category", headerSort: false,
editor:"autocomplete", width: 250,
editorParams:{
   values:["red", "green", "blue", "orange"],  
   allowEmpty: true,
   showListOnEmpty : true
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi..We encourage you to get involved in the community, but please don’t thank in the question. It eventually degrades the quality of the site. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem statement ?  I created a sandbox of your problem but its working fine for me. You can check it in the code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-fog-cep40)